# If statements not evaluating to true when they should?

Tags: java

I'm a complete Java noob. This code runs fine with no compiling errors, but when I stepped through the program I discovered that the if statements at the bottom never evaluated to true. What am I missing?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rps {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      println("Select rock (0), paper (1), or scissors (2)");
      String input = scanner.nextLine();

      if (Integer.parseInt(input) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(input) > 2) {
         input = Long.toString(Math.round(Math.random() * 2));
      }

      if (input == "0") {
         println("You played rock");
      } else if (input == "1") {
         println("You played paper");
      } else if (input == "2") {
         println("You played scissors");
      }
   }

   static void println(String a) {
      System.out.println(a);
   }
}
```

Comment: `String` comparison in Java should be done using `input.equals(value)`. Try changing it

Comment: Hey, that works! Thank you :D

Comment: Please go through the above-marked link (duplicate) for better understanding.